# Determinining uniform convergence for $f_{n}(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k}{k^2x^2+2n^2}$ over $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, sequence-of-function

**Problem**.

> Consider the sequence of functions $\displaystyle f_{n}:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$, with $\displaystyle f_{n}(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k}{k^2x^2+2n^2}$. I want to determine whether $\left\{f_{n} \right\}$ converges uniformly.

---

Writing
$$f_n(x)=\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\frac kn}{\left(\frac kn\right)^2x^2+2},$$
I know that $\left\{f_{n} \right\}$ converges pointwisely to $$f(x)= \begin{cases}
\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1} \frac{t}{x^2t^2+2}dt, & \text{if }\; x\neq 0, \\
\displaystyle \frac{1}{4},& \text{if }\; x=0, \\
\end{cases}$$ but I can't determine whether the convergence is uniform or not.

Comment: Note that the integral formula for $f(x)$ gives $1/4$ when $x=0$, so you do not need to distinguish two cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let
$$F(x,t)=\frac t{x^2t^2+2},\qquad x\in\mathbb R, \ t\in[0,1].$$
Then $f_n(x)=\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^nF\left(x,\frac kn\right)$ and thus
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)=\int_0^1F(x,t)\,dt=:f(x).$$
We claim that
$$\sup_{x\in\mathbb R}|f_n(x)-f(x)|\leq\frac1{4n}.\tag{1}$$
As a result, we see that $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$. Now we prove $(1)$.
\begin{align*}
|f_n(x)-f(x)|&=\left|\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^nF\left(x,\frac kn\right)-\int_0^1F(x,t)\,dt\right|\\
&=\left|\sum_{k=1}^n\int_{\frac{k-1}n}^\frac kn\left[F\left(x,\frac kn\right)-F(x,t)\right]\,dt\right|\\
&\leq \sum_{k=1}^n\int_{\frac{k-1}n}^\frac kn\left|F\left(x,\frac kn\right)-F(x,t)\right|\,dt.
\end{align*}
We use mean value theorem to estimate $\left|F\left(x,\frac kn\right)-F(x,t)\right|$. We calculate that
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial t}(x,t)=\frac{2-x^2t^2}{(x^2t^2+2)^2}=\frac4{(x^2t^2+2)^2}-\frac1{x^2t^2+2},\qquad x\in\mathbb R, t\in[0,1].$$
Consider $\phi(s)=4s^2-s$ for $s\in(0,1/2]$, then $|\phi(s)|\leq \max\{|\phi(1/8)|,|\phi(1/2)|\}=\phi(1/2)=\frac12$. Hence
$$\left|\frac{\partial F}{\partial t}(x,t)\right|\leq\frac12,\qquad x\in\mathbb R, \ t\in[0,1],$$ and thus $\left|F\left(x,\frac kn\right)-F(x,t)\right|\leq \frac12\left|\frac kn-t\right|$ by mean value theorem. Therefore,
\begin{align*}
|f_n(x)-f(x)|&\leq\sum_{k=1}^n\int_{\frac{k-1}n}^\frac kn\left|F\left(x,\frac kn\right)-F(x,t)\right|\,dt\\
&\leq\frac12 \sum_{k=1}^n\int_{\frac{k-1}n}^\frac kn\left|\frac kn-t\right|\,dt\\
&=\frac14\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{n^2}=\frac1{4n}.
\end{align*}
This gives the inequality $(1)$ and thus completes the proof of the uniform convergence.